# Drupal won't allow me or other users to remove images

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-6

Uploading images etc are fine.

But when it comes to removing an image the following ajax error comes up:

> An HTTP error 500 occurred. 
>   /filefield/ahah/news/field_images/0

This results in users now not being able to modify images on news articles.

Help!

Comment: Could you remove images before?

Comment: Have you checked the drupal log and the webserver error logs (especially the latter, as 500 indicates an 'Internal Server Error', so it should show up there)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the same problem: http://drupal.org/node/434394